Clipboard Package And Gdef N Argument Conflict
I use Eduardo Louren ̧co de Lima’s excellent Clipboard package in several documents.
In one recent usage, I embedded a \gdef command within the \Copy command. The \gdef command includes the n argument #1.
Source Document Code:
\Copy{Preamble-permissible-operations-how-to-be-assured-of-having-latest-data}{
\gdef\PreamblePermissibleOperationsHowToBeAssuredOfHavingLatestData#1{
\section*{PERMISSIBLE OPERATIONS}
The {#1} takes a positive approach.  Lorem ipsum.

\section*{HOW TO BE ASSURED OF HAVING LATEST DATA}
Refer to the {#1} Flyleaf.  Also, check the {#1} title page, and, all status pages contained in the {#1}.  Lorem ipsum
}
}
\PreamblePermissibleOperationsHowToBeAssuredOfHavingLatestData{\fltmanLUC}

Destination Document Code:
\Paste{Preamble-permissible-operations-how-to-be-assured-of-having-latest-data}
\PreamblePermissibleOperationsHowToBeAssuredOfHavingLatestData{\wpnsmanLUC}

When I compile the source document, LaTeX generates five error messages (each of which requires depressing the RETURN key to resume compilation), which correspond to the five occurrences of #1. However, the source PDF does display my desired content, correctly. If I remove each occurrence of #1, LaTeX produces one less error message for each removal.
The same five error messages are:
./DocumentName.tex:9106: Illegal parameter number in definition of
\clipboard@Preamble-permissible-operations-how-to-be-assured-of-having-latest-data.
<to be read again>
1
l.9106 }

When I compile the destination document, LaTeX generates no error messages. The destination PDF displays my desired content, correctly.
How can I include the characters #1 within the \Copy command, such that Clipboard will acknowledge them properly, rather than consider them to be illegal parameters?
Thank you for any and all assistance.

Try with ##1 instead of #1

Hi, Ulrike.
Thank you for your suggestion.
I had tried this solution, previously.  LaTeX produced the errors:
Parameters must be numbered consecutively.

##
and
Paragraph ended before \PreamblePermissibleOpe
rationsHowToBeAssuredOfHavingLatestData was complete.

\par
The PDF output does not display the information that is contained within the \gdef command.

The current definition of \clipboard@copy and \clipboard@write don't support # in the body. A detour with a toks register solves the issue.
Using the code in the documentation, with a \gdef inside.
File test.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{clipboard}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\clipboard@copy}[2]{%
  \toks@={#2}%
  \global\expandafter\edef\csname clipboard@#1\endcsname{\the\toks@}%
}
\renewcommand{\clipboard@write}[2]{%
  \immediate\write\clipboard@fileout{%
    \string\clipboard{#1}{\detokenize{#2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newclipboard{myclipboard}

\begin{document}

\Copy{dolorem ipsum}{Nor again is there anyone who
  loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself%
  \gdef\aaaaa#1{--#1--}%
},
  because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur
 in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure.

\texttt{\meaning\aaaaa}

\end{document}


File testpaste.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clipboard}

\openclipboard{myclipboard}

\begin{document}

According to Cicero,
\begin{quote}
  \Paste{dolorem ipsum}
\end{quote}

\texttt{\meaning\aaaaa}

\end{document}



Hi, egreg.
Thank you for your suggestion.
I copied your \makeatletter code, and, I pasted into my document.
LaTeX produced repeated errors, starting with:
Runaway argument?
{ \gdef \PreamblePermissibleOperationsHowToBeAssuredOfHavingLatestData \ETC.
Paragraph ended before \clipboard@copy was com
plete.

\par
?
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in
horizontal mode.
 ...Y \ for a listing of all current {##
1}s, \osLUCYYY s, \ssLUCYY...

@KurtTodoroff Can you please add a full example starting from \documentclass up to \end{document}, using human names instead of those humongous strings?

The Clipboard package developer suggested a solution.  I simplified it.
Source Doc:
\gdef\ClipboardFltManOrWpnsMan{\fltmanLUC}
\Copy{Preamble-permissible-operations-how-to-be-assured-of-having-latest-data}{
\section*{PERMISSIBLE OPERATIONS}
The \ClipboardFltManOrWpnsMan\ takes a positive approach.  Lorem ipsum.
}
\Paste{Flight-Manual-Preamble-permissible-operations-how-to-be-assured-of-having-latest-data}
Destination Doc:
\gdef\ClipboardFltManOrWpnsMan{\wpnsmanLUC}
\Paste{Flight-Manual-Preamble-permissible-operations-how-to-be-assured-of-having-latest-data}
It works.

@KurtTodoroffI can’t follow unreadable comments.

@KurtTodoroff Anyway, I think I've seen the problem: try with the modified code. Of course, you're still missing to provide a full example. For instance, what's \fltmanLUC?

@egreg Kurt's question boils down to how to support \def, \newcommand, etc. taking one or more parameters within \Copy. A possible MWE is: \documentclass{article}\usepackage{clipboard}\begin{document}\Copy{key}{\newcommand\foo[1]{#1}\foo{bar}}\end{document}. Your solution seems to work. Thanks. As this is the first time I've used \toks, I'm wondering if applying it as a patch to the clipboard package may not break older code. Do you think it's safe?

@eduardo.tex I see no issue and that's a known trick. Note also the \detokenize in \clipboard@write which avoids other possible issues.
